# No manifest file from maven build

Tags: maven, war

I'm using Maven to generate a war file. I'm trying to get it to generate a manifest file in the war. Right now it's not happening. I've included the following in my pom.xml, but I can't get it to output a manifest file with that information. Anyone have any ideas or pointers? There is no MANIFEST.mf being put into the war.

```
<project>
   <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        ...
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
              <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        ...
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Have you done a mvn clean package ? BTW: maven-war-plugin is currently at version 2.2...

Comment: Did the clean and then updated the plugin version. Not sure which it was but it's working now. Thanks.

Comment: Did you change anything in your POM file? I am literally having the same problem but I'm using version 2.2 of the maven-war-plugin.

Answer (score 7):

You should add this to your plugin config:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>manifest</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```